# How to autoinsert date in second field after there were already inserted some date into the 1st field?

Tags: javascript, html, date

Lets say i have two fields:

```
Start Date: <input type="date" name=""/>
End Date: <input type="date" name=""/>
```

I want when i add for example 03/12/2014 in the first field to autoinsert 7 days after the added date into the 2nd field ( in this case it will be 10/12/2014).

I will make my question more clear.

```
<title>Ha</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

I use jquery datepicker calendar. 
And here are my fields:

```
<div class='ddate'><p>Start date:<input type="date" id="datepicker" name="d1" required="required"></p></div>
                        <div class='ddate'><p>End date:<input type="date" id="datepicker1" name="d2" ></p></div>
```

So i should use some JS function or ?

Comment: do you have access to any libraries like jQuery or Angular? What have you tried so far? The tags definitely should not have the same value for the `name` attribute and should ideally have an `id` attribute.

Comment: what javascript code are you trying onto.
You can use Date to add days to the `StartDate` by simply adding the no of days converted to microseconds. i.e. current_date + 7days*24*60*60*1000. Then convert it to a new Date object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can simply attach an on event when start date changes ...

```
Start Date: <input type="date" name="date" id="start_date" />
End Date: <input type="date" name="date" id="end_date" />
```

... then ...

```
$("#start_date").on('blur', function() {
    var self = this;

    var new_date = new Date($(self).val());
    new_date.setDate(new_date.getDate() + 8);
    $("#end_date").val(new_date.yyyymmdd());
});

Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {                                     
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();                                    
    var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based         
    var dd  = this.getDate().toString();             

    return yyyy + '-' + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + '-' + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]);
};
```

See **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/dnz2n5z1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Doing date math in Javascript is hard because the native Date object in Javascript is one of the more poorly implemented objects in the language.  My goto date library is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

The below code should get you pretty close and show you how to validate the fields for invalid date strings.

```
var $startDate = $('#startDate'),
    $endDate = $('#endDate');


$startDate.on('change', function(e) {
  var currentDate = moment($(this).val(), "YYYY-MM-DD");
  $startDate.css('background', 'none');

  if (currentDate.isValid()) {
    var weekLater = currentDate.add(7, 'days');
    $endDate.val(weekLater.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  } else {
    $startDate.css('background', 'red');
  }
});
```

EDIT:
Working example http://jsbin.com/puwaco/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Like the use of moment.js!